# error al intentar mostrar informacion de un registro q esta en un listado , laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

hola tengo el siguiente error al intentar recuperar toda la informacion de un registro q esta en un listado , para luego visualizarlo .

> QueryException in Connection.php line 666: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
>   found: 1054 Unknown column 'vista_transporte.id' in 'where clause'
>   (SQL: select * from `vista_transporte` where `vista_transporte`.`id` =
>   835818 limit 1)

esta es mi tabla vista_transporte

```
protected $table = 'vista_transporte';

protected$fillable = ['cod_proveedor',
                      'cod_liquidacion',
                      'trans_1',
                      'transportista',
                      'proveedor',
                      'fecha_ingreso',
                      'fecha_pago',
                      'nombre_completo',
                      'ci',
                      'placa'];
```

vista  pago_transporte.blade. php donde esta el listado

```
<thead>
    <th>Codigo</th>
    <th>Proveedor</th>
    <th>Transportista</th>
    <th>Vista Factura</th>
  </thead>
  @foreach($datos_transporte as $trans)
  <tbody>
    <td>{{$trans->cod_liquidacion}}</td>
    <td>{{$trans->proveedor}}</td>
    <td>{{$trans->transportista}}</td>
    <td>
        {!!link_to_route('factura.show',$title = 'Ver factura',$parameters = $trans->cod_liquidacion, $attributes=['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}
```

la ruta a la que se hace referencia

```
Route::resource('factura','FacturasController');
```

controlador FacturasController
funcion a la que va despues de hacer click en el boton del listado (ver factura)

```
public function show($cod_liquidacion)
     {
       $code_liq = \IMSUR\transpor::find($cod_liquidacion);
       return view ('transportes.show',compact('code_liq'));
     }
```

vista  show.blade.php
- vista donde deveria mostrar la informacion del registro q seleccionamos

```
<table class="table table-bordered">

    <thead>
      <th>Cod liquidacion</th>
      <th>Fecha ingreso</th>
      <th>Transportista</th>

    </thead>
    @foreach ($code_liq as $code)
    <tbody>
      <td>{{$code->cod_liquidacion}}</td>
      <td>{{$code->proveedor}}</td>
      <td>{{$code->transportista}}</td>

    </tbody>
    @endforeach
  </table>
```

eso seria todo aguardare por sus respuestas grasias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Estás seguro de que tu tabla "`vista_transporte`" tiene la columna "`id`"?

Intenta encontrar el transporte por su código de liquidación , prueba algo así :

```
public function show($cod_liquidacion)
     {
       $code_liq = \IMSUR\transpor::where('cod_liquidacion',$cod_liquidacion)->firstOrFail();
       return view ('transportes.show',compact('code_liq'));
     }
```

Comment: hola chaval segui lo que publicaste pero ahora me sale este error   ||||                                                         
                                                                                           
ErrorException in 7b1f6f9648ea381a95849de23c71a74d line 15: Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\web-imsur-laravel\resources\views\transportes\show.blade.php)

Answer (score 1):

Aquí veo una confusión con las rutas para resources: Resulta que al definir un conjunto de rutas con `Route::resource()`, se está haciendo uso de implicit route model binding (al menos de la forma como lo hace el OP en la pregunta) y podemos aprovechar dicha funcionalidad directamente en el controlador (de hecho se puede crear el controlador con estos parámetros de forma automática). Sin embargo, parece ser que no está utilizando una llave primaria para la búsqueda, lo cual a simple vista parece innecesario, o tal vez haya que replantear algunas propiedades del modelo y algunos procedimientos.

Cuando se utilizan rutas para resources (recursos), lo ideal es pasar la llave primaria al momento de inyectar en el método del controlador, así que voy a suponer que `$cod_liquidacion` es una llave primaria:

```
public function show(transpor $cod_liquidacion)
{
    return view ('transportes.show', compact('cod_liquidacion'));
}
```

De esta forma no es necesario ni siquiera obtener el modelo (ya lo hace el route model binding por nosotros), y el código es mucho más limpio y conciso. Esto es lo que llaman «la magia de Laravel».

Comment: hola chaval estaba aplicando tu respuesta y me salio el siguiente error |||||  ReflectionException in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 81: Class IMSUR\Http\Controllers\transpor does not exist

Comment: La idea no es solo implementarla, ¿entiendes todo lo que implica utilizar la solución de la forma que la planteo?

Comment: lo siento pero no, estoy empezando con este lenguaje de programacion y framework y la verdad me esta costando adaptarme

Answer (score 0):

**Observaciones**

- Toma en cuenta que estas usando el método `find` el cual intentaá hacer uso de la columna `id` *en caso de existir* en tu tabla.

El punto anterior lo puedes comprobar si accedes a la siguiente ruta en tu proyecto:

```
proyecto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent
```

Notarás esta propiedad declarada:

```
/**
     * The primary key for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
```

> No modifiques aquí dicha propiedad, lo que haremos es un *override* de la misma pero a nivel del modelo vinculado a tu tabla, checa el siguiente punto

- En caso de que dicha columna no esté respetando la convención de nombre `id`, deberás en tu modelo declarar una propiedad que ayude a Eloquent a saber cual es la `PK`

Declaración de la propiedad `$primaryKey`:

```
class Modelo extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'columna_id';
}
```

Además de lo anterior, recomiendo uses el método `findOrFail()` para que en caso de no encontrar un registro asociado a la clave que le pases, retorne una excepción.

Quedando tu consulta de este modo:

```
$code_liq = \IMSUR\transpor::findOrFail($cod_liquidacion);
```

> Esto último te será útil por que en caso de no encontrar un registro, el resultado retornado será un *Error 404* referente a que lo que tratas de encontrar no existe.

**Referencias**

- [`findOrFail`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)
- [`primaryKey`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

Comment: Gran respuesta @Aprendiz te lo curras mucho! +1

Comment: hola amigo hice lo q esta en tu publicacion pero ahora me sale este error |||||||||               
                                                                                          
 ErrorException in 7b1f6f9648ea381a95849de23c71a74d line 15: Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\web-imsur-laravel\resources\views\transportes\show.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

hola chavales mientras aplicaba sus respuestas en la primera y en la tecera respuesta me sale este error

ErrorException in 7b1f6f9648ea381a95849de23c71a74d line 15: Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\web-imsur-laravel\resources\views\transportes\show.blade.php)

las correxiones q hice segun sus respuestas fue con la primera respuesta

en controlador FacturasController

```
public function show($cod_liquidacion)
     {
       $code_liq = \IMSUR\transpor::where('cod_liquidacion',$cod_liquidacion)->firstOrFail();
       return view ('transportes.show',compact('code_liq'));
     }
```

en el modelo transpor

```
class transpor extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'cod_liquidacion';        /// aumentado


    protected $table = 'vista_transporte';

    protected$fillable = ['cod_proveedor',
                          'cod_liquidacion',
                          'trans_1',
                          'transportista',
                          'proveedor',
                          'fecha_ingreso',
                          'fecha_pago',
                          'nombre_completo',
                          'ci',
                          'placa'];
```

ahora en la tercera respuesta

cambios en controllador

```
public function show($cod_liquidacion)
     {
       $code_liq = \IMSUR\transpor::findOrFail($cod_liquidacion);
       return view ('transportes.show',compact('code_liq'));
     }
```

cambios en modelo transpor

```
 class transpor extends Model
    {
        protected $primaryKey = 'cod_liquidacion';        /// aumentado


        protected $table = 'vista_transporte';

        protected$fillable = ['cod_proveedor',
                              'cod_liquidacion',
                              'trans_1',
                              'transportista',
                              'proveedor',
                              'fecha_ingreso',
                              'fecha_pago',
                              'nombre_completo',
                              'ci',
                              'placa'];
```

y en la segunda respuesta me salio el siguiente error

ReflectionException in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 81: Class IMSUR\Http\Controllers\transpor does not exist

cambios echos en FacturasController

```
use  IMSUR\Http\Controllers\transpor;
```

cambios en funcion show

```
public function show(transpor $cod_liquidacion)
     {
       return view ('transportes.show', compact('cod_liquidacion'));
     }
```

cambios en vista show.blade.php

```
<table class="table table-bordered">

    <thead>
      <th>Cod liquidacion</th>
      <th>Fecha ingreso</th>
      <th>Transportista</th>

    </thead>
    @foreach ($cod_liquidacion as $code)     /// modificado de code_liq  a  cod_liquidacion
    <tbody>
      <td>{{$code->cod_proveedor}}</td>
      <td>{{$code->cod_liquidacion}}</td>
      <td>{{$code->trans_1}}</td>

    </tbody>
    @endforeach
  </table>
```

aguardare sus respuestas y grasias